# How do I solve this kind of circular dependencies?

Tags: unlocked-package, architecture

In our project, we are trying to divide the different functionalities into separate unlocked packages. While trying to divide the metadata into different packages we've encountered this case of circular dependency and can't find a solution that allows us to split the metadata into two or more packages.

I'll summarize it, though it's better understood in the image:

We have the blue package containing CustomObject1 with org actionOverrides from View to a Flexipage, and the green package with CustomObject2 has a lookup field referencing CustomObject1. All this poses no problem, but in the Flexipage, we have some force:relatedListSingleContainer to include child records of type CustomObject2 in the view of CustomObject1.

[image]

Is there any way out of this deadlock? I had thought about creating a third package for the Flexipage that would depend on the other two, but then I can't put the actionOverrides of the View of CustomObject1 because the dependency ends in two directions.

What is usually done in these cases? Do you apply the actionOverride manually after each installation? That's the only thing that occurs to me, or changing the force:relatedListSingleContainer for a customized Lightning web component that doesn't create a hard dependency with CustomObject2.

I appreciate any ideas or recommendations. Thank you very much!

Comment: Are you sure you will get benefit from using more than one package? What benefit do you expect? Multiple packages also mean e.g. multiple sets of permission sets. And difficulty sharing utility code. So one package may be the better KISS (= less time/money, less stress) solution.

Comment: This is a simplified schema of the issue, but within each of those packages, there are several dozen metadata elements related to each functionality. In the end, we're somewhat victims of Conway's Law because there's a team that owns each of the packages, and we wanted to find a solution that could allow teams to work independently without blocking each other. Something similar to working following the idea of "open for extension, but closed for modification."

Comment: Makes sense. Personally I'd handle the working together part in GitHub (branches etc, running CI) and treat the single package as a delivery mechanism.